# How do I add footseplines?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage, footer, scrreprt

I have set up a documentclass like this

```
\documentclass[
    11pt,                  % Font size
    final,
    cleardoublepage = plain, % just for page numbers on cleardoublepages
    parskip=half,          % Half a line skipped between paragraphs
    twoside,               % Two-sided document
    openright,             % Chapters start on right pages
    bibliography=totoc,    % Bibliography in ToC
    listof=totoc,          % LoF and LoT in ToC
    footsepline=0.4pt,
]{scrreprt}[2015/09/15]    % Use current version of KOMA-Script
% Author and title of document

% Header and footer
\usepackage[automark,headwidth=textwithmarginpar,footwidth=text,footsepline=0.4pt, headsepline=0.4pt:textwithmarginpar]{scrlayer-scrpage}  % Custom header and footer
\usepackage{lastpage} %needed for page number
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\setfootsepline{.4pt} THAT DIDNT WORK__________________________________________
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\@chapapp~\thechapter~--~#1}{}}
\makeatother
\rohead{\rightmark}
\lehead{\leftmark}
```

The footsepline appears, but only on pages wich a) contains text and b) arent the first page of a new chapter. How do I change that, so that footseplines appear on every page with a footer?

Comment: Off-topic: If you'd use `\chapapp` instead of `\@chapapp` you won't need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. And `\rohead{\rightmark}`, `\lehead{\leftmark}` AFAIK can be replaced by `\ohead{\headmark}`. BTW: You should always show a MWE instead of only a snippet from the preamble.

Comment: BTW: 2015/09/15 is not the [current version of KOMA-Script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) but refers to outdated v3.18.

Comment: Schweinebacke thank you. Cleaned it up a bit. What does MWE stand for?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! See : [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the option `plainfootsepline`:

```
\documentclass[
    11pt,                  % Font size
    final,
    cleardoublepage = plain, % just for page numbers on cleardoublepages
    parskip=half,          % Half a line skipped between paragraphs
    twoside,               % Two-sided document
    openright,             % Chapters start on right pages
    bibliography=totoc,    % Bibliography in ToC
    listof=totoc,          % LoF and LoT in ToC
]{scrreprt}[2015/09/15]    % Use current version of KOMA-Script
% Author and title of document

% Header and footer
\usepackage[automark,headwidth=textwithmarginpar,footwidth=text,
            footsepline=0.4pt, 
            headsepline=0.4pt:textwithmarginpar,
            plainfootsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}  % Custom header and footer
\usepackage{lastpage} %needed for page number
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\@chapapp~\thechapter~--~#1}{}}
\makeatother
\rohead{\rightmark}
\lehead{\leftmark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A}

\chapter{B}
\newpage
blblblb

\end{document}
```